# Calling Stored Procedure From Db Context with an non mapped entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

What I am trying to understand is how to call a stored procedure using a DbContext and return an object that is not an entity, OK let me explain a little bit more in case I am not getting the terminology correct

I have a C# Code First Data Context, it has the entity models and mapping models for the tables in the database. I also have about ten stored procedures that return reporting data, none of these stored procedure map to any of the entities I have.

What I would like to do is create a class which represents a row generated by the stored procedure and some how call its corresponding stored procedure with parameters  and get a List out.

I have tried this asan attempted to understand what is happening with a simple stored procedure returning 5 rows of data and only two columns

```
public class ReportA
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private MyContext _context = new MyContext();

public List<ReportA> GetReportA(DateTime startDate)
    {

var parameters = new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@Startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
            {
                IsNullable = false,
                Value = startDate
            }
        };



 var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<List<reportA>>(
            "dbo.ReportA @Startdate", parameters);

return result
}
```

it fires but I get nothing back. Any advice or help would be appreciated

Comment: It's not as simple as adding .ToList() on the end of your query is it? SqlQuery just returns a raw query, you need to call .ToList() to actually materialise the data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ReportA>(
    "dbo.ReportA @Startdate", parameters);
```

instead of this code:

```
var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<List<ReportA>>(
    "dbo.ReportA @Startdate", parameters);
```

Notice I'm using `SqlQuery<ReportA>` and not `SqlQuery<List<ReportA>`>. The template of `SqlQuery` method should be the type that the entities will be mapped and not the type of your result.

Comment: I also added a .ToList() to the var result when returning the data,  return result.ToList(); and its working thank you very much